# Como fazer um "deep copy" em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte código:

```
class Foo:
    pass


foo_list = [Foo() for _ in range(10)]
```

Como posso proceder para criar uma cópia de `foo_list` sem que as referências, tanto da lista quanto dos objetos nela contidos, sejam passados para a próxima lista?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O que estás a fazer é apenas uma [*shallow copy* (cópia superficial)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#copy.copy).

[DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances)

Tradução:

> A diferença entre cópia superficial e cópia profunda só é relevante
>   para objetos compostos, * **é o teu caso**, (objetos que contêm outros
>   objetos, como listas ou instâncias de classes)

#### deep copy (cópia profunda):

```
import copy

y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
x = copy.deepcopy(y)
x[0].append(10)

print(y) # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(x) # [[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6]]
print(id(y[0])) # 140313159068680
print(id(x[0])) # 140313158999816
```

Aqui, `x` e `y`, e tudo o que lhes pertence, são 'considerados' objetos diferentes/independentes, as referências aos seus objetos internos são diferentes e por isso é possível operar em cada um sem afetar o outro contido na outra lista.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MvYz/1)

#### shallow copy (cópia superficial):

```
y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
x = y[:]
x[0].append(10)

print(y) # [[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6]]
print(x) # [[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6]]
print(id(y[0])) # 139853165128712
print(id(x[0])) # 139853165128712
```

Aqui, os objetos internos de `x` e `y` têm exatamente as mesmas referências, e por isso partilham literalmente os mesmos objetos/valores.

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/Mv05/1)

Usando o teu exemplo para [demonstrar](https://ideone.com/kkeqQQ) as diferenças:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Foo: pass

foo = Foo()
foo.bar = 10

shallow_copies = [foo for _ in range(10)] # todos os foo partilham as mesmas referencias internas
deep_copies = [deepcopy(foo) for _ in range(10)] # copias independentes, referencias diferentes

shallow_copies[0].bar = 100 # mudar valor da propriedade do primeiro foo
deep_copies[0].bar = 100 # mudar valor da propriedade do primeiro foo

print([f.bar for f in shallow_copies]) # [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
print([f.bar for f in deep_copies]) # [100, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
print(all(f.bar is shallow_copies[0].bar for f in shallow_copies[1:])) # True , todos os foo tem bar com a mesma ref
print(all(f.bar is deep_copies[0].bar for f in deep_copies[1:])) # False
```