# Como clonar uma lista com Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

A partir lista `m`:

```
 m =   [[' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # '], [' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # '], [' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # '], [' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # '], [' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # '], [' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ', ' # ']]
```

Ao fazer `mb = m[:]` ou `mb = list(m)` eu clonaria a `m` inicial, certo ou não? Mas ao fazer `mb[0][0] = 99999999`, por exemplo, a lista `m` também é modificada.

O que não estou enxergando ou não sei sobre o assunto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema principal é que você possui uma lista de objetos mutáveis - neste caso, uma lista de listas. Então apenas fazer uma cópia rasa não será suficiente.

Para copiar os objetos mutáveis da sua lista, para que não mantenham a referência, você precisará fazer a cópia profunda.

- [Como fazer um "deep copy" em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247588/5878)
- [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/5878)

Assim, basta fazer:

```
from copy import deepcopy

mb = deepcopy(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias possibilidades:

```
>>> lista = [1, 2, 3]
>>> copia = lista.copy()
>>> copia
[1, 2, 3]
>>> copia = lista[:]
>>> copia
[1, 2, 3]
```

Além do que em muitos scripts você e capaz de ver algo como:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
copia = []
for item in lista:
    copia.append(item)
print(copia) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Algo contrário do você disse fazer `lista[:]` não gera uma referência a a lista original mas sim uma cópia da mesma, ou seja alterar a cópia não altera a original.

Comment: Terá o mesmo problema da outra resposta, que foi excluída. O que ele tem é uma lista de listas, que são tipos mutáveis. Mesmo fazendo a cópia rasa, com `copy`, as referências dos objetos internos permanecerão na nova lista. Se uma delas for alterada, a alteração se refletirá na original. Veja em: https://repl.it/@acwoss/DisfiguredStrictBase