# Variável atribuída a outra altera variável pai

Tags: python-3.x, lista, variáveis

Olá, estou tendo um problema com Python3: Quando crio uma lista e atribuo o valor de outra variável a essa lista, quando altero a variável a lista é alterada, código:

```py
lista = ["uau", "nossa"]
lista1 = lista
lista1[0] = "impressionante"
print(lista1, lista)
# retorna ['impressionante', 'nossa'] ['impressionante', 'nossa']
```

Gostaria que a variável "lista" parasse de mudar e somente a "lista1" mudasse, também gostaria se pudesse me falar por que isso ocorre, obrigado.

Comment: Vinculadas: [Como clonar uma lista com Python 3?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325592/5878) | [O que “imutável” realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/5878) | [Por que listas (arrays) tem um comportamento diferentes das variáveis comuns em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408221/5878) | [Listas dentro de listas: mesmo fatiando, há conexão entre as listas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341040/5878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que quando você faz isso, você referencia uma lista à outra, então para você não criar essa referência de objetos, você teria que fazer uma cópia. Basta adicionar o método `copy`, veja:

```py
lista = ["uau", "nossa"]
lista1 = lista.copy()

lista1[0] = "impressionante"

print(lista1, lista) # ['impressionante', 'nossa'] ['uau', 'nossa']
```

Com vetores multidimensionais, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

lista = [["uau", "nossa"]]
lista1 = deepcopy(lista)

lista1[0][0] = "impressionante"

print(lista1, lista) # [['impressionante', 'nossa']] [['uau', 'nossa']]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada :) Se possível marcar a resposta em ✔

Comment: Tem que aguardar um pouco

Comment: Como eu faço isso com listas bidimensionais? Estou tentando e dá erro

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo usando lista multidimensional :)