# Como salvar um dicionário em dois objetos independentes no Python?

Tags: python, objetos, dicionário

Considere os seguintes dicionários:

```
dic1 = {'k1':'Ford','k2':'GM','k3':'Dodge'}
dic2 = {'k4':'Audi','k5':'Mercedes','k6':'VW'}
dic3 = {'k7':'Fiat','k8':'Mazda'}
```

O objetivo é obter dois novos dicionários, de modo que dic4 seja a união de dic1 e dic2

```
{'k1':'Ford','k2':'GM','k3':'Dodge','k4':'Audi','k5':'Mercedes','k6':'VW'}
```

e dic5 a a união de dic1 e dic3

```
{'k1':'Ford','k2':'GM','k3':'Dodge','k7':'Fiat','k8':'Mazda'}
```

A questão aqui é manter dic1, dic2 e dic3 inalterados, de modo que possam ser utilizados novamente. A princípio pensei em fazer `dic1.update(dic2)`, mas aí eu perderia o dicionário original.

Há alguma forma de armazenar dic1 em dois objetos com nomes diferentes (por exemplo dicx e dicy) e então trabalhar somente com eles para montar os dicionários dic4 e dic5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa é [criar uma cópia](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) de `dic1` e depois fazer o `update` na cópia:

```
dic1 = {'k1':'Ford','k2':'GM','k3':'Dodge'}
dic2 = {'k4':'Audi','k5':'Mercedes','k6':'VW'}
dic3 = {'k7':'Fiat','k8':'Mazda'}

dic4 = dic1.copy()
dic4.update(dic2)

dic5 = dic1.copy()
dic5.update(dic3)
```

Ou ainda:

```
dic4 = dict(dic1)
dic4.update(dic2)

dic5 = dict(dic1)
dic5.update(dic3)
```

Com isso, `dic1`, `dic2` e `dic3` permanecem inalterados.

Lembrando que `copy` retorna uma *shallow copy* - isso pode fazer diferença dependendo do tipo de objeto que tem no dicionário, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247588/112052) para entender melhor.

---

Outra opção, apontada pelo [@Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5749/miguel) nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492919/como-salvar-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-em-dois-objetos-independentes-no-python/492922?noredirect=1#comment916065_492922):

```
dic4 = { **dic1, **dic2 }
dic5 = { **dic1, **dic3 }
```

---

Por fim, a partir do Python 3.9 é possível usar o operador `|`, que cria um novo dicionário contendo as chaves de ambos os operandos:

```
dic1 = {'k1':'Ford','k2':'GM','k3':'Dodge'}
dic2 = {'k4':'Audi','k5':'Mercedes','k6':'VW'}
dic3 = {'k7':'Fiat','k8':'Mazda'}

dic4 = dic1 | dic2

dic5 = dic1 | dic3
```

Comment: Olá @hkotsubo https://ideone.com/RbRe7T, apenas duas alternativas, caso seja python3.5+

Comment: @Miguel Acho que vale uma resposta, hein  :-) (principalmente a primeira opção, que eu não sabia que era possível)

Comment: Sim a segunda é basicamente o teu update, não vou conseguir responder porque estou no telefone e isto não dá jeito nenhum, mas podes complementar a resposta se achares adequado

Comment: @Miguel OK, atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!!

Answer (score 4):

No Python 3.9 você tem a união com pipe "|".

```
dic4 = dic1 | dic2
```

Em versões anteriores você pode fazer o seginte:

```
dic4 = dic1.copy()
dic4.update(dic2)
```

A necessidade do `copy` é devido ao fato de dicionários serem estrutura de dados do tipo **mutável**. Veja mais sobre tipos mutáveis e imutáveis [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478735/valor-de-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1-alterando-automaticamente).

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!!